# How to get the exactly object from different class?

Tags: java, android

I create an Object:

```
public class Info {
    private ArrayList<Object> list;

    public Info(){
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public Info getInfo(){
        return this;
    }
    public void put(final byte[] macAddress, final String name) {
        HashMap<byte[], String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(macAddress,name);

       list.add(map);
    }
    public ArrayList getList(){
        return list;
    }
```

}

and I new Info in a class

```
Info info = new Info();
info.put(mAddress1,mName1);
info.put(mAddress2,mName2);
```

But I want to get this object from the other class. How can I get this Object?(I only create/new it once)

Comment: get the object from other class means? Do you want to make the class info singleton?

Comment: you can achieve this using parcelable in intent

Comment: you just create once in any class then pass that object to intent using parcelable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Make the Info class singleton**

```
    public class Info {
      public static Info info;
      private ArrayList<Object> list;

      public static Info getInstance(){
        if(info == null)
           info = new Info();
        return info;
      }    

      private Info(){
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
      }

      public void put(final byte[] macAddress, final String name) {
        HashMap<byte[], String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(macAddress,name);

        list.add(map);
      }

      public ArrayList getList(){
        return list;
      }
    }
```

**2. Usage**

```
Info info = Info.getInstance();
info.put(mAddress1,mName1);
info.put(mAddress2,mName2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the same object. try to use HashMap and implement equals and hashCode methods and based on key get the object.
another idea

create instance variable of Info class in you another class and while creating instance in parameterized constructor send this info object and assign that value

suppose you another class is ABC

```
Info info = new Info();
info.put(mAddress1,mName1);
info.put(mAddress2,mName2);
ABC abc=new ABC(info);


class ABC{
Info info;
public ABC(Info info)
this.info=info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [Singleton Class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm).

> the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the
>   instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly
>   one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system

```
public class Info {
    private Info(){
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
      this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public static Info info = null;

    public static Info getinstance(){
        if(info == null) info = new Info();

        return info;
    }

    private ArrayList<Object> list;



    public Info(){
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public Info getInfo(){
        return this;
    }
    public void put(final byte[] macAddress, final String name) {
        HashMap<byte[], String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(macAddress,name);

       list.add(map);
    }
    public ArrayList getList(){
        return list;
    }
```